# Login with Caliburn.Micro WinRT

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, caliburn.micro

I have a LoginViewModel and LoginView that allows a user to log into app if they want to access their favorites. My question is how to update the MainView to add a "Favorites" header to the grouped GridView and save the credentials of the user once they have logged in. Can someone point me to the right direction? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Something along this was how I have been storing settings on Win81 since there is nothing in CM yet for storing of settings on page change like in Windows Phone

```
private ApplicationDataContainer _settings;

_settings = new Application.Data.LocalSettings  //in the OnInitialize() or CTOR

_settings.Values["UserName"] = UserName;
```

if the value doesn't exist in the _settings container it might require some logic to set it up

```
if(!_settings.Values.Contains("UserName"))
   _settings.Values.Add("UserName", "");
```

as for the first part of the question I haven't put any thought into it... hope this steers you the right direction for the settings or saving something of the nature.

Comment: where do I set this up, in the app.cs or somewhere else?

Comment: sure you could set it up in the app.cs some of what I did is there but most stuff I do on each page change I do so I can track authentication and or user change.